# My custom HTTP error message is getting overwritten in php

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, apache2, webserver

So I using cakephp and using ajax to submit forms. In some cases it returns a custom error.

For example, at one point it can be like:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 412 
([{"field":"PaymentCardholderName","message":"Please enter CardHolder's Name."},
{"field":"PaymentCardNumber","message":"Please enter Card Number."},
{"field":"PaymentCvvNumber","message":"Please enter CVV Number."},
{"field":"PaymentBillingAddress","message":"Please enter your Billing Address"}])
```

Here is the server logic in case anyone needs it

```
header('HTTP/1.1 412 ' . json_encode($error));
```

when I open this up locally I see my custom error message. When I deploy it to a remote server I just see my custom error message overwritten

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 412 
(Precondition Failed)
```

It must be some configuration, but I can't find it.

Comment: Why on *earth* would you put data like this in the response line? Put it in the body of the response (`echo` it) - HTTP is *not* designed to work in the way you are attempting to use it.

Comment: @DaveRandom thanks for the response. I am trying to trigger a jquery ajax error . can u plz help me with that . how can i send the error in this case

Comment: Please add the jQ code that makes the request to your question so we can assist you with correct code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally, instead of presuming `HTTP/1.1`

Do this:

```
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 412 Precondition Failed");
```

Instead of this:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 412 Precondition Failed");
header("HTTP/1.0 412 Precondition Failed");
```

Why? Because `$_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]` gives you either `HTTP/1.1` or `HTTP/1.0` based on your browser. If you use the wrong one, apache might add unexpected content to the response. eg. a 4 digit hex code at the start (checksum?), and a trailing zero.

Comment: And on top of that, the status line should never be relied on. It's intended as a human-readable string only. Code should only ever look at the code.